# Does the superman style have any chance to be seen in competition?

Tags: technique, riding-position

On social networks, many people have seen Michael Guerra's superman style.

[image]

## [Video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvmibwafGXc)

The technique seems to be quite efficient, however it probably requires skills and yield to increase risks of falling. Also such technique is only worth it in long descents.

Is there any chance that such technique could be seen in high level competition such as the Tour de France for example?

Comment: No, the racer will lost valuable time to enact such stunt. There is a question of returning to pedaling posture.

Comment: Notice he's on a fixie?

Comment: I'm mostly impressed by his ability to clip back in on a brakeless fixie at speed

Comment: It would only really be worth it on a not-too-long, *shallow* descent.  Anything much steeper than what's depicted in the picture would almost certainly require that the rider control his speed at some point.  Plus on a long descent ones speed is apt to increase steadily until one is going too fast to control the bike.  It would make a *little* more sense if the bike had hand brakes.  (Keep in mind that in a "normal" riding position the rider can control his downhill speed to a large degree by changing profile.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I really doubt it. A number of problems pop into my head immediately.

1. Corners.
2. French/Italian/Spanish road surfaces.
3. Holding your legs up long enough to be worth it.
4. I'm pretty sure this video is staged.

Chris Froome caused a stir this year at the Tour just sitting on his top tube and that looked sketchy enough at 100kmh, twitchy and uncomfortable.